# df.to.csv using strings and variable does not work pandas 1.3.5

Tags: python, pandas

works:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\monro\.spyder-py3\pythonProject1\data\_'  + stock_name + '.csv' )
```

does not work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\monro\.spyder-py3\pythonProject1\data\'  + stock_name + '.csv' )
```

Why would the underline make a difference?

Comment: In the title: `df.to.csv`? You mean `pd.read_csv` instead? You're trying to load 2 different files - I guess one, the second, doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, pd.read_csv is correct.
The first line is correct without parse error and the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pd.read_csv is correct. Sorry.
The first line is correct without parse error and the file does not exist. The second line is fails parse and the file exists.

Original command is:

> Blockquote
> df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\monro.spyder-py3\pythonProject1\data\TQQQ.csv')
> I want TQQQ to be a variable for flexibility.

Comment: Reversed slashes to work
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/monro/.spyder-py3/pythonProject1/data/'  + stock_name + '.csv' )

Close this issue